# ssl gives ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error on tomcat 6 + jsf 2.0

Tags: ssl, jsf-2, tomcat6

I used this [3 easy steps](http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/) tutorial to setup SSL on Tomcat 6. I did it step by step. I've even changed the `<connector>` to be the same as in the tutorial. Unfortunately after restarting Tomcat and running the project i had ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error

here is what I did:

1. Run command `keytool -genkey -alias techtracer -keypass ttadmin -keystore techtracer.bin -storepass ttadmin` in java bin folder
2. answer questions
3. copy the techtracer.bin file into tomcats webapps directory
4. modify tomcats conf/server.xml file as follows

`

```
<Connector port=”8443″
maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
enableLookups=”true” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
acceptCount=”100″ debug=”0″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS”
keystoreFile=”../webapps/techtracer.bin”
keystorePass=”ttadmin” />
```

`
5.modify web.xml file in jsf app as follows

add this code:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

in addition typing https://localhost:8443/ in the browser results with outcome "The connection was terminated while the page was loading". I don't know what causes this problem. Please show me the right direction. Thank You in advance

**Resolved:**

1. Run command `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA` in java bin folder
2. answer questions
3. modify tomcats conf/server.xml file as follows

`

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="C:/Users/Szajba/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

`
5.modify web.xml file in jsf app as follows

add this code:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Works fine for me. Remember to change the password

Comment: There were probably two main issues here: Tomcat 6 needs the SSLEnabled="true" attribute, and the keystoreFile relative path is resolved to $CATALINA_BASE, which was probably the tomcat home directory in your case, so the relative path in the first example does not seem to be correct (looks like you thought it was relative to the tomcat/conf directory).